# Laravel 8: QueueManager.php:156 array offset of type null / Configure redis

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, redis, queue

I am about to setup `Redis` and `Laravel Horizon`. Although I have set up everything correctly (I assume) I get a very weird error. `Laravel` tells me that it is `Trying to access array offset on value of type null` at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php:156`

The line `156` is the first return line:

```
/**
* Resolve a queue connection.
*
* @param  string  $name
* @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue
*/
protected function resolve($name)
{
    $config = $this->getConfig($name);

    return $this->getConnector($config['driver']) // <-- This line
                    ->connect($config)
                    ->setConnectionName($name);
}
```

So, I assume `Laravel` cannot access `$config['driver']`. But when I do a `dd` of `$config` I get the following:

```
array:5 [
  "driver" => "redis"
  "connection" => "default"
  "queue" => "default"
  "retry_after" => 90
  "block_for" => null
]
```

So, it is **impossible** that `driver` is empty because as you can see `driver` is set to `redis`. Do you guys have any idea why `Laravel` cannot `access array offset on value of type null`?

I have installed `phpredis`, a `Redis database` and also `Laravel Horizon`. When I try to access my `/horizon` I get the same error as above.

`phpredis` is installed correctly. I have added `extension=redis.so` to my `php.ini` and when I execute `php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"` in my command line I also get `OK`. So, it cannot be `phpredis`.

My `Redis database` is also working:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

And my configs are also correct. This is my `.env` (just some entries):

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Here is my `config/queue.php`:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Queue Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel's queue API supports an assortment of back-ends via a single
    | API, giving you convenient access to each back-end using the same
    | syntax for every one. Here you may define a default connection.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the connection information for each server that
    | is used by your application. A default configuration has been added
    | for each back-end shipped with Laravel. You are free to add more.
    |
    | Drivers: "sync", "database", "beanstalkd", "sqs", "redis", "null"
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Failed Queue Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configure the behavior of failed queue job logging so you
    | can control which database and table are used to store the jobs that
    | have failed. You may change them to any database / table you wish.
    |
    */

    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

My `config/horizon.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the subdomain where Horizon will be accessible from. If this
    | setting is null, Horizon will reside under the same domain as the
    | application. Otherwise, this value will serve as the subdomain.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('HORIZEN_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the URI path where Horizon will be accessible from. Feel free
    | to change this path to anything you like. Note that the URI will not
    | affect the paths of its internal API that aren't exposed to users.
    |
    */

    'path' => env('HORIZEN_PATH', 'horizon'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Redis Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the name of the Redis connection where Horizon will store the
    | meta information required for it to function. It includes the list
    | of supervisors, failed jobs, job metrics, and other information.
    |
    */

    'use' => 'default',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Redis Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This prefix will be used when storing all Horizon data in Redis. You
    | may modify the prefix when you are running multiple installations
    | of Horizon on the same server so that they don't have problems.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env(
        'HORIZON_PREFIX',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_horizon:'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Route Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These middleware will get attached onto each Horizon route, giving you
    | the chance to add your own middleware to this list or change any of
    | the existing middleware. Or, you can simply stick with this list.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Wait Time Thresholds
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to configure when the LongWaitDetected event
    | will be fired. Every connection / queue combination may have its
    | own, unique threshold (in seconds) before this event is fired.
    |
    */

    'waits' => [
        'redis:default' => 60,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Job Trimming Times
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you can configure for how long (in minutes) you desire Horizon to
    | persist the recent and failed jobs. Typically, recent jobs are kept
    | for one hour while all failed jobs are stored for an entire week.
    |
    */

    'trim' => [
        'recent' => 60,
        'pending' => 60,
        'completed' => 60,
        'recent_failed' => 10080,
        'failed' => 10080,
        'monitored' => 10080,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Metrics
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you can configure how many snapshots should be kept to display in
    | the metrics graph. This will get used in combination with Horizon's
    | `horizon:snapshot` schedule to define how long to retain metrics.
    |
    */

    'metrics' => [
        'trim_snapshots' => [
            'job' => 24,
            'queue' => 24,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fast Termination
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, Horizon's "terminate" command will not
    | wait on all of the workers to terminate unless the --wait option
    | is provided. Fast termination can shorten deployment delay by
    | allowing a new instance of Horizon to start while the last
    | instance will continue to terminate each of its workers.
    |
    */

    'fast_termination' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Memory Limit (MB)
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value describes the maximum amount of memory the Horizon master
    | supervisor may consume before it is terminated and restarted. For
    | configuring these limits on your workers, see the next section.
    |
    */

    'memory_limit' => 64,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Worker Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the queue worker settings used by your application
    | in all environments. These supervisors and settings handle all your
    | queued jobs and will be provisioned by Horizon during deployment.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'maxProcesses' => 1,
            'memory' => 128,
            'tries' => 1,
            'nice' => 0,
        ],
    ],

    'environments' => [
        'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 2,
                'timeout' => 60 * 60,
            ],
            'mailcoach-general' => [
                'connection' => 'mailcoach-redis',
                'queue' => ['mailcoach', 'mailcoach-feedback', 'send-mail'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 2,
                'timeout' => 60 * 60,
            ],
            'mailcoach-heavy' => [
                'connection' => 'mailcoach-redis',
                'queue' => ['send-campaign'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 3,
                'tries' => 1,
                'timeout' => 60 * 60,
            ],
        ],

        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 2,
                'timeout' => 60 * 60,
            ],
            'mailcoach-general' => [
                'connection' => 'mailcoach-redis',
                'queue' => ['mailcoach', 'mailcoach-feedback', 'send-mail'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 2,
                'timeout' => 60 * 60,
            ],
            'mailcoach-heavy' => [
                'connection' => 'mailcoach-redis',
                'queue' => ['send-campaign'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 3,
                'tries' => 1,
                'timeout' => 60 * 60,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Anyone has an idea why I get this error?
I am working on `php 7.4.16`, `10.5.6-MariaDB`, `redis-cli 6.2.1` and on `Laravel Framework 8.32.1`. So, everything is on the newest version.

I would appreciate any kind of help!
Kind regards

Comment: And you are running the queue via supervisor for example? Or manually via php artisan?
I have a similar setup for all my projects (only with docker containers) and always use queue workers

Comment: Then we can do some troubleshooting... I always use supervisor to run my queue worker processes, I think you should too. Let me know how you currently run the queue workers and we go from there Jan

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ray. I am just running it with the command `php artisan horizon`. Should I do something else?

Comment: And can you see the Horizon entries in your Redis keys then? I'd still use supervisor though but theoretically just doing `php artisan horizon` should ofc also work with the right config.
Also... you have tested your redis setup? I mean you can do a `$redisclient->set('bla');` and it appears in your Redis keys * (via redis-cli)

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet but I will asap. I have created an issue on laravel github which is now closed because I have not created the repo as requested but I will soon. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/36613

Comment: CLOSED: I am very sorry.. I found my error.. The `queue.php` file was missing the `mailcoach-redis` connection... I am very sorry!

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you've got it to work. Please also consider using supervisor, it's got some advantages especially it's more failproof due to auto-restarting the queue. Cheers

Comment: Yes, will do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

- Edit: I just thought of something... your Redis setup is functioning correctly right? I mean when you do a `$redisclient->setex('test', 123, 'value');` it shows up in your redis-cli right when you do `keys test`?

Ok let's go through how I would set this up and troubleshoot this.
Your error I believe is in the "final stages" of the whole process, let's first check if the queues are running ok etc.
So I'm using Docker Containers but that shouldn't matter.
I think Horizon is really good, especially compared to using the default "queue:work", due to the dashboard and monitoring you've got access to.

As I said, I think it is a good idea to use the supervisor service to run the queue workers, also as mentioned in the Laravel docs:

```
To keep the queue:work process running permanently in the background, you should use a process monitor such as Supervisor to ensure that the queue worker does not stop running.
```

The reason why is really that it auto-restarts your queues etc in case of errors.
So below I went through a bit, possibly excessive supervisor stuff...

So the moving parts are:

- Supervisor > queue worker proces(ses): Horizon
- Redis
- Laravel app

As I said I'm running Supervisor in my Docker PHP-FPM container which in it's turn runs cron, Horizon and PHP-FPM but in your case you can just install Supervisor with apt-get like so https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon#installing-supervisor and just let it run horizon.
Doing it this way I can also point you out to the log file which will be created which might tell us some more details :)
Make sure after installing supervisor and adding the example-hotizon.conf config file to your conf.d directory you do a `supervisor reread` (rereads the config files) and then a `supervisor update` process config changes.

====== START SUPERVISOR ======

My Horizon Supervisor config:

```
[program:example-horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/example.com/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/example.com/storage/logs/horizon.log
# Kill the job after "stopwaitsecs" secs, make sure this is greater than the longest running job
stopwaitsecs=600
```

Then I think you can just do `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`
With my supervisord.conf being like so, I have taken out my Cron and PHP-FPM configs...:

```
; http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock               ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                                  ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true                               ; This keeps the Docker container alive (in the foreground)
user=root                                   ; default user
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid            ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid) 
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor             ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface 

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock   ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket 

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

I assume you have also already published Horizon right? `php artisan horizon:publish` after you did `php artisan horizon:install` I believe to use the dashboard functionality.

Let's test what this will output by keeping an eye no:

- our supervisor console
- Our log file /var/www/example.com/storage/logs/horizon.log (set in horizon.conf)

So let's start with our supervisor console.
run `supervisorctl` from your command prompt, you'll see your running processes strait away, hoping that your example-horizon process is actually "RUNNING" and not "STOPPED" or simmilar.
You can also check the log by, from supervisorctl, running tail <process_name> so `tail example-horizon` and check that output.
[image: supervisor log example]
In my case of `supervisorctl status` I have:

```
# supervisorctl status
cron                             RUNNING   pid 8, uptime 3 days, 22:09:07
example-horizon                  RUNNING   pid 10, uptime 3 days, 22:09:07
php-fpm                          RUNNING   pid 9, uptime 3 days, 22:09:07
```

====== END SUPERVISOR ======

====== START REDIS ======

Then when the supervisor part is working I assume your Redis config is fine in your .env but what you can do is check your Redis if it has the Horizon queue keys in it:
[image: Redis output]
Mine are called "horizon_LW1_xxx" because I have used "horizon_LW1" as a prefix for horizon in the Horizon config `config/horizon.php`, mine looks like:

```
'prefix' => env(
        'HORIZON_PREFIX',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_horizon:'
    ),
```

In case you don't have this in your Redis we should fix that first...

====== END REDIS ======

====== config/horizon.php ======
Just my local horizon config depending on my env "HOZIRON_QUEUE_LOCAL" which are my different queues:
`HOZIRON_QUEUE_LOCAL=prio1,prio2,email,default`

```
'local' => [
            'supervisor-it' => [
                'queue' => explode(',', env('HOZIRON_QUEUE_LOCAL', 'default')),
                'maxProcesses' => 23,
                'memory' => 100,
            ],
        ],
```

Let's just fire a job into the queue, monitoring your supervisor "tail example-horizon" (storage/logs/horizon.log), your Laravel log (storage/logs/laravel.log) and your Redis queue.

Sorry this became a bit of a novel, but basically:

1. install Supervisor
2. run Horizon queue via Supervisor
3. check Redis keys
4. check logs (supervisor, laravel)

Let me know how the above goes as I believe they are the "roots" of a good Horizon setup.
Then we can move on to the next step in case that does not work out successful yet.